# The Admin Directory users.list request returns 400 Bad request

Tags: google-api, google-apis-explorer

This happens in the API Explorer and using the .NET client API.  In the API Explorer, I was trying to use the query param, but eventually I just removed it and now send the request with no params, and it still turns around 400 even though I am authenticating successfully with OAuth2 in browser.

Why is this endpoint broken?

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list

Comment: Can you post your request?

Comment: @JBLovell see answer i just posted

Answer (score 9):

The problem was the `customer` field was not filled in.  It must contain a valid customer id.  Once I populated that, it worked.

Really wish Google would work on providing better error feedback and improve their docs.  This field (as of today) is still listed as optional.

Comment: How do you find your customer id?

Comment: Instruction how to find the customer id: https://support.google.com/a/answer/10070793

Comment: For "customer" param you can also use alias "my_customer" to represent your account's customerId.
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/groups/list

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation says:

> either the customer or the domain parameter must be provided

I tried to specify `domain` name and it worked.